# Confused with the concept of degrees in polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let's say I have a function $ f(x) = (x + 1)^2 (2x^2 + 5) (x + 4)$ , and this function can also be $ f(x) = 2x^5 + 12x^4 + 23x^3 + 38x^2 + 45x + 20,$  would the degree of the function be $2$ or $5$? Which highest exponent should I choose when finding the degree of a polynomial?

Comment: It would be five.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @md2perpe thanks for the links! Will use them next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

To decide the degree of the polynomial you need to fully expand it out. So if I wanted to know the degree of the polynomial $f(x)=(x+1)(x-1)$ you need to expand the parentheses and write it as $f(x)=x^2-1$ to declare its degree is $2$. There is actually a shorter way of doing this though. If you have the polynomial written as some product of other polynomials, e.g $f(x)=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)$ then the degree of $f$ is the sum of the highest degrees in each of its factors, i.e $\operatorname{deg}f=2+1=3$. In general, if you have a polynomial say
$$P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i(x)^{r_i}$$
Then
$$\operatorname{deg}P=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\cdot \operatorname{deg}p_i$$

Comment: You don't need to expand a polynomial to determine its degree. For example, what is the degree of $(x^2+2x-5)(x+8)(x^4-x^2)$? Using our knowledge of how multiplication works  you should be able to quickly deduce that this is a polynomial of degree 7.

Comment: @JohnDouma Did you even read my answer....

Comment: Yes. "To decide the degree of the polynomial you need to fully expand it out. "

Comment: I just noticed that you added the shortcut at the end of your post. I apologize. I am not used to a writing style where you first assert something and later say it isn't necessarily true.